# Validar arquivo csv em django

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando inserir uma função para validar o upload de um .csv, porém ao colocá-la o seguinte erro foi apresentado:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'PresencaProf' from partially initialized module 'parte1.models' (most likely due to a circular import)`

Eu pesquisei, mas nenhuma solução foi útil para mim. Eu não sei sobre o que se trata esse erro, apenas ganhei uma noção quando vi sobre a execução sequencial, mas não se encaixou, pois até onde eu vi, tudo estava certo.

Arquivo `forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import forms
from django import forms
from parte1.models import PresencaProf, PresencaAula


class UploadArquivo(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = PresencaProf
        fields = ('evento', 'data', 'upload_csv',)


        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UploadArquivo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for visible in self.visible_fields():
                visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

        # Funcao para validar extensao csv
        def valida_csv_extensao(value):
            if not value.fk_evento__nome_evento.endswith('.csv'):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Erro!\nApenas arquivos .csv !")

        def clean(self):
            data = super(UploadArquivo, self).clean()
```

Toda ajuda é bem vinda!!!

Arquivo `models.py`:

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from django.db import models
from chamadas import forms


class PresencaProf(models.Model):

    data = models.DateField()
    evento = models.ForeignKey(Eventos, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    # validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['csv'] -> valida um csv
    upload_csv = models.FileField(upload_to = 'csv', blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Regristo de presença"
        verbose_name_plural = "Registros de presenças"


class PresencaAula(models.Model):

    # atributo que pega o ID de um evento, relacionamento 1:N
    fk_evento = models.ForeignKey(Eventos, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True, blank=True)
    fk_professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True, blank=True)
    data_aula = models.DateField()

    class Meta:

        verbose_name = "Presença por aula"
        verbose_name_plural = "Presenças por aulas"
```

Comment: no forms.py você tem `from parte1.models import PresencaProf, PresencaAula` e no models.py `from chamadas import forms`. Em outras palavras, A importa B e B import A. Isso resulta no `import circular`. Eu diria quer você *não* precisa carregar o forms de dentro do models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nas importações do seu **models.py**

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from django.db import models
from chamadas import forms
```

retira a útlima linha:

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from django.db import models
```

Essas referências circulares normalmente são causadas por importações, então sempre dá uma checada...

Comment: Muito obrigada, deu certo. Agora os erros são outros kkkkk. Obrigada, de verdade!